# Controlled table quering based on existing rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a **product_group** table with the following fields: group_id, product_id, order. The table will be queried against a lot: a single-form view will make it possible to insert new records and/or update existing ones with one submit.

I'm trying to figure out optimal solution to cover the following 3 cases:

1. **User tries to insert an existing row:** do nothing. Here a unique index of the 3 columns can be useful.
2. **User changes only the order column:** perform an update.
3. **User inserts a completely new set of values:** perform an insert.

Is there a way to put all of this together in one MySQL query? If not, what would be the best approach here? The goal is to limit database queries as much as possible.

Comment: a stored procedure would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
insert into product_group(group_id, product_id, `order`)
    values (@group_id, @product_id, @order)
    on duplicate key update `order` = values(`order`);
```

Along with a unique index on `group_id, product_id`:

```
create unique index idx_product_group_2 on product_group(group_id, product_id)
```

This handles your three cases:

1. Because the value assignment is a no-op if the values are the same.
2. The `order` column will be updated if the other two have the same value.
3. A new row that has a different `group_id` or `product_id` will be inserted.

As a note, `order` is a lousy name for a column, because it is a SQL key word.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean I need 2 unique indexes - one on all and one on first two columns? The order column holds explicit order of products in which they're displayed. I'll change the name.

Comment: OK, I didn't need the 3-column index, I got it. One thing: I needed to change `SET` to `UPDATE` in the `on duplicate key set` part (because of invalid syntax). I edited it above. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think you need a unique index on all three columns, just one on the first two.

Comment: Exactly, the third one is redundant. I didn't grasp the idea at first, but then I did ;)